# Anylogic: Why is my SelectOutput with agent variable value condition not working?

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, probability, anylogic, agent

I have a `SelectOutput` block in my Anylogic model that tests the variable `probabilityhub` of the agent going through the process blocks. If it is higher than 0.5, it is false and the agent should go down.

[image]

The variable `probabilityhub` is given in the `TOD` delay block like `agent.probabilityhub =` *some formula*.  I checked to see if the variable is given to the agents correctly, by writing them in a dataset at the exit of delay block `TOD` (like `dataset.add(agent.othervariable,agent.probabilityhub);`) and as you can see in the dataset, it works and the `probabilityhub` sometimes is higher than 0.5. However, as you also can see in the figure below, the `SelectOutput` is always true and none of the agents are going down... Does anyone know why this could be the case?

[image]

Comment: Could it be related to the type of the variable? Maybe it takes it as a string?

Comment: This is a common problem and there are many similar questions in the AnyLogic tag...Also check this blog post for more details - https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/select-output-misbehaving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the action "on exit" of the delay block occurs AFTER the selectOutput condition calculation, so if you change the value of your probability on the on exit action, it's too late... This is counterintuitive in anylogic but things happen in the reverse order of the flow... which is weird, but it is like that

So calculate it in the "on at exit" action instead, and everything will work

Comment: Felipe is correct, there are a ton of similar questions here already, check those as well. Common problem :)